# Bootstrap 3: force button to bottom of grid container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I get my Submit button to be placed at the bottom of the right column in my form?  It should be to the right of the "text 6" input box -- **not** at top against bottom of "text 8" as shown in image.

[image]

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EvjZbb?editors=1100)

```
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <fieldset>
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 1" />
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 2" />
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 3" />
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 4" />
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 5" />
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 6" />
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <fieldset>
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 7" />
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 8" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <button class="center-block btn btn-primary" type="submit">
            Send</button>
          </button>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

I've tried all the various positioning suggestions I could find here on S.O., but they all manage to fail in one way or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a fancy new CSS `display: grid`

You can use `grid-gap: 5px;`  in order to add some spacing if you want. Limited pretty hard to the latest browsers, but this works really well.

More reading: http://gridbyexample.com

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KvpaOm

CSS

```
.special-container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.special-container button{
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 6;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
  <form>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 special-container">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 1" />
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 2" />
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 3" />
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 4" />
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 5" />
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 6" />
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 7" />
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 8" />
      <button class="center-block btn btn-primary" type="submit">
        Send
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: This does not seem to work in Safari 9.1, although it does work nicely in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Yeah, Safari 10.1 minimum. Works on iOS Safari though. so long as it's up to date. https://gridbyexample.com/browsers/

Comment: Not sure you're going to find a perfect solution without grid though. Vertically aligning things is hard with CSS unless you have fixed heights.

Comment: Yep, I didn't think it was going to be an easy problem, but Stack Overflow has the best minds out there!

Comment: I had another answer which put the button in a different container below everything then pulled it up using negative margin. I can add that one back in if you think that'll work better for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try a new `row`

```
<body>
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <fieldset>
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 1" />
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 2" />
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 3" />
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 4" />
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 5" />
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 6" />
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <fieldset>
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 7" />
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 8" />
        </fieldset>        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <fieldset>
          <button class="center-block btn btn-primary" type="submit">
            Send</button>
          </button>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

EDIT: After seeing your photo, this is not exactly what you want. For that, you will have to play some more with css.

Comment: As an alternative, this is pretty nice since I can snug the button up against the bottom of the grid boxes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add margin-top like this:

```
.btn {
margin-top:100px;
}
```

Comment: If it's guaranteed there won't be any inputs added, then yeah. This is actually the simplest thing to do.

Comment: Right.  There's lots of ways I could do this by simply adding explicit spacing, but the perfectionist in me wants to find a good, general solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go about it would be to place the button below the inputs and pull it up into the space using a negative margin on the top. This doesn't account for differently sized buttons, but as said in the comments of my other solution this isn't a problem that will have many clean solutions.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxpVer

CSS:

```
.special-container button{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 25%;
  margin-top: -33px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <fieldset>
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 1" />
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 2" />
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 3" />
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 4" />
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 5" />
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 6" />
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <fieldset>
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 7" />
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="text 8" />
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 special-container">
        <fieldset>
          <button class="center-block btn btn-primary" type="submit">
            Send</button>
          </button>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```